# After reaching given index in list, I should save the position to can move backward and forward

Tags: python

I am sharing the whole task condition to make sense to you!

```
Move

Description
Your task is to calculate the sum of all forward and all backwards moves in an array. On the input you will receive the starting point, the array itself with all the values. After that you will receive multiple lines with instructions in the format [Steps Direction Size] separated by single space until you receive exit.

The starting position must be read from the console. Direction could be forward or backwards. If you get out of the boundaries of the array you should enter from the other side. The starting position is not included in the sum.

As final result you must print the result for forward moves and the result for the backwards as well.

Example:
0
10,20,30,40,50
2 forward 1
2 backwards 1
3 forward 2
3 backwards 2
exit

We start at position 0.
We move 2 times forward with size 1 => sum = 20 + 30 = 50
We move 2 times backwards with size 1 => sum = 20 + 10 = 30
We move 3 times forward with size 2 => sum = 30 + 50 + 20 = 100
We move 3 time backwards with size 2 => sum = 50 + 30 + 10 = 90
Forward = 150
Backwards = 120

Input

All input data is read from the standard input (the console)

On the first line you will receive the starting point in the array (it is not included in the sum)
On the second line you will receive the array as a string (comma delimited integers)
On the next lines until you find exit command you will receive strings in format [Steps Direction Size] delimited by single space

Output

The output data is printed on the standard output (the console)

On the first line you should print the sum of forward moves Forward: forward sum
On the second line you should print the sum of backwards moves Backwards: backwards sum

Constraints

The integers in the array will be in the range [0, 10000]
The steps will be an integer in the range [0, 10000]
The direction will be string in format "forward" or "backwards"
The size will be an integer in the range [0, 10000]
The input data will always be correct and there is no need to check it explicitly

Sample Tests

Sample Input 1

0
10,20,30,40,50
2 forward 1
2 backwards 1
3 forward 2
3 backwards 2
exit

Sample Output 1
Forward: 150
Backwards: 120

Sample Input 2

4
10,20,30,40,50
2 forward 1
2 backwards 1
3 forward 2
3 backwards 2
exit

Sample Output 2

Forward: 100
Backwards: 170

Sample Input 3

0
10,20
1 forward 1
2 backwards 1
1 forward 1
exit

Sample Output 3

Forward: 30
Backwards: 30
```

Here is the code that I wrote and it is about 50% of the condition, but I just struggled.

```
start = int(input())

Array = input()

elements = Array.split(',')

int_array = [int(elem) for elem in elements]

start_position = int_array[start:]

forward = []

backward = []

while True:

    instructions = input().split()
    if instructions[0] == 'exit':
        break

    steps = int(instructions[0])
    direction = instructions[1]
    size = int(instructions[2])

    for i in range(steps):
        if direction == 'forward':
            if i+1 < len(start_position):
                stop_tochka = start_position[i+1]
                forward.append(start_position[i+1])
            else:
                break  
        elif direction == 'backwards':
            pass
```

The problem is in the for loop, because according to the condition, if the first instruction is "2 forward 1" and then the second instruction is "2 backwards 1", I should get back from the index that I reached in the first "forward" instruction, and I don't have idea, how to do it on code.

Comment: Use `%` (modulo) such that if your position goes "out of bounds", it loops back again. `new_pos = (old_pos + change) % len(array)` Play with `%` and you'll see it's easy to handle forward as a positive change and backward as a negative change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `%` operator to make the index "wrap" within the bounds of the array.  You also don't need to store the individual positions; you can just keep a running sum as you iterate over each range.

Converting the direction into a numeric value (i.e `+1` or `-1`) means you can just multiply the `size` by it rather than needing a separate block of code for each direction:

```
i = int(input())
array = [int(n) for n in input().split(",")]
results = {+1: 0, -1: 0}

while True:
    move = input().split()
    if move == ["exit"]:
        break

    steps = int(move[0])
    direction = {
        "forward": +1,
        "backwards": -1,
    }[move[1]]  # raises KeyError on invalid input
    size = int(move[2]) * direction

    results[direction] += sum(
        array[(i + step * size) % len(array)]
        for step in range(1, steps + 1)
    )
    i += steps * size

print("Forward:", results[+1])
print("Backwards:", results[-1])
```

```
0
10,20,30,40,50
2 forward 1
2 backwards 1
3 forward 2
3 backwards 2
exit
Forward: 150
Backwards: 120
```